# drupal 6 can we write a php file in drupal which changes the headers

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-panels

i have written a small code which creates a word document but 
i got the following errors

require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
global $user;

```
$fp = fopen("test.doc", 'w+');
$str = "<B>This is the text for the word file created through php programming</B><br>test to create a doc file from php";
ob_start();
    include('index.php');
    $result = ob_get_clean();

fwrite($fp, $result);
    echo "executed";
```

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.doc");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("test.doc"));
header("Connection: close");

```
fclose($fp);
```

?>
warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already comnt by (output started at /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php:6) in /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php on line 19.
warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already comnt by (output started at /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php:6) in /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php on line 20.
warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already comnt by (output started at /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php:6) in /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php on line 21.
warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already comnt by (output started at /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php:6) in /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/test_createdoc.php on line 22

**i have even remove the white spaces between php tags**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `echo "executed";` sends output before the headers. PHP then stops the headers from sending, because HTTP requires headers to come before output. If removing that doesn't fix it, try commenting out `include('index.php');` to test if the output is coming from there.